# the client/server application is not working correctly

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, client-server

When I launch `server.cpp` then I immediately get the phrase `"Client Connected!"`, although I have not launched the application for `client.cpp` yet. When I launch the application for `client.cpp`, I have nothing output in the console.

I understand that this happens to me because I have an application running `server.cpp` and the variable `newConnection` is equal to `18446744073709551615` for some reason. I tried changing ports, IP addresses, but nothing helps.

server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>//библиотека ввода вывода
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>//библиотека windows для работы с сетью
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //подключили библиотеку
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }//1-ый параметр запрашиваемая версия библиотеки


    //заполнение информации об адресе сокета
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;//название интернет протокола
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.2.2.2");//хранит ip адрес 
    addr.sin_port = htons(4321);//порт
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;//симейство протоколов


    //для установления соединения
    //прослушивание на определенном порту
    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);//создание сокета, SOCK_STREAM - протокол, который устанавливает соединение
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));//привязываем адрес и порт к сокету, 2-ой параметр - указатель на SOCKADDR_IN adrr, 3-ий - размер SOCKADDR_IN adrr
    //прослушивание порта в ожидании соединения со стороны клиента
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);//SOMAXCONN - максимальное число запрос ожидающих обработки


    //новый сокет чтобы удерживать соединение с клиентом
    SOCKET newConnection;
    newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &sizeofaddr); //accept возвращает указатель на новый сокет. второй параметр будет содержать ip адрес клиента, который произвел подключение

    if (newConnection == 0) {
        cout << "Error #2\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Client Connected!\n" << newConnection;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>//библиотека ввода вывода
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>//библиотека windows для работы с сетью
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //подключили библиотеку
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }//1-ый параметр запрашиваемая версия библиотеки


    //заполнение информации об адресе сокета
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;//название интернет протокола
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.2.2.2");//хранит ip адрес 
    addr.sin_port = htons(4321);//порт
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;//симейство протоколов


    //создание сокета для соединения с сервером
    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);//создание сокета, SOCK_STREAM - протокол, который устанавливает соединение
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) !=0) {
        cout << "Errror: failed connect to server.\n";
        return 1;
    }//пытаемся соединиться с сервером

    cout << "Connected to server!\n";
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `18446744073709551615` is `-1`/`INVALID_SOCKET`, check the error code using `WSAGetLastError` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept. You should also check that `bind` and `listen` succeed

Comment: Side note : but I do not like the windows api for socket programming. boost::asio has a much better C++ api and is portable too (I have used both apis)

Comment: Your test `if (newConnection == 0)` is incorrect. It should be `if (newConnection == INVALID_SOCKET)`. `accept()` does not return 0 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

In `server.cpp`, the expression:

`if (newConnection == 0)`

needs to be this instead:

`if (newConnection == INVALID_SOCKET)`

`accept()` does NOT return `0` on failure, as you have coded.

In a 64bit build, the `INVALID_SOCKET` constant has an unsigned integer value of `18446744073709551615`. Which means `accept()` is failing in your case, but you are not treating it as a failure, which is why you are seeing `Client Connected!` instead of `Error #2`.

You need to use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out WHY a socket function failed, eg:

server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>//библиотека ввода вывода
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>//библиотека windows для работы с сетью
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //подключили библиотеку
    WSAData wsaData;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup() failed, error " << err << endl;
        return 1;
    }//1-ый параметр запрашиваемая версия библиотеки


    //заполнение информации об адресе сокета
    SOCKADDR_IN addr = {};//название интернет протокола
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.2.2.2");//хранит ip адрес 
    addr.sin_port = htons(4321);//порт
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;//симейство протоколов

    //для установления соединения
    //прослушивание на определенном порту
    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);//создание сокета, SOCK_STREAM - протокол, который устанавливает соединение
    if (sListen == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "socket() failed, error " << err << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) { //привязываем адрес и порт к сокету, 2-ой параметр - указатель на SOCKADDR_IN adrr, 3-ий - размер SOCKADDR_IN adrr
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "bind() failed, error " << err << endl;
        closesocket(sListen);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //прослушивание порта в ожидании соединения со стороны клиента
    if (listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) { //SOMAXCONN - максимальное число запрос ожидающих обработки
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "listen() failed, error " << err << endl;
        closesocket(sListen);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //новый сокет чтобы удерживать соединение с клиентом
    SOCKET newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &sizeofaddr); //accept возвращает указатель на новый сокет. второй параметр будет содержать ip адрес клиента, который произвел подключение
    if (newConnection == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "accept() failed, error " << err << endl;
        closesocket(sListen);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Client Connected!\n";

    system("pause");

    closesocket(newConnection);
    closesocket(sListen);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>//библиотека ввода вывода
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>//библиотека windows для работы с сетью
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //подключили библиотеку
    WSAData wsaData;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup() failed, error " << err << endl;
        return 1;
    }//1-ый параметр запрашиваемая версия библиотеки

    //заполнение информации об адресе сокета
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;//название интернет протокола
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.2.2.2");//хранит ip адрес 
    addr.sin_port = htons(4321);//порт
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;//симейство протоколов

    //создание сокета для соединения с сервером
    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);//создание сокета, SOCK_STREAM - протокол, который устанавливает соединение
    if (Connection == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "socket() failed, error " << err << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "connect() failed, error " << err << endl;
        closesocket(Connection);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }//пытаемся соединиться с сервером

    cout << "Connected to server!\n";
    
    system("pause");

    closesocket(Connection);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the error is in "bind, error 10049". I just don't understand, I can specify any ip address and port for the connection, the main thing is that they are the same for the client and the server, or is some specific ip and port needed?

Comment: everything worked, just pointed to server.cpp instead of "inet_addr("172.2.2.2")". this is "htonl(INADDR_ANY)", thanks for the advice and the rewritten code with WSAGetLastError()

Comment: @Jeez [Winsock error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) 10049 is `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`. For [`bind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind), that error means: "*The requested address is not valid in its context. This error is returned if the specified address pointed to by the name parameter is not a valid local IP address on this computer.*"  Which means you tried to bind the server to an IP address that doesn't belong to the machine that your server is running on.